# DUKPT / BDK Generation

Tags: encryption

I am new to DUKPT.  I am in need of generating a BDK for a Project that involves POS transactions. The requirement for BDK is 3DES with 16 bytes key,  with Keying Option 1 where all the keys are independent.  How do I generate this BDK using openssl and also need to get an output key file so we can give it the application folks for the decryption of the POS transactions. Already have the KSN. Familiar with the IPEK generation process.  Just need to know how to generate BDK. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The BDK should generated and stored on Tamper Resistant Security Modules (TRSM) usually an Hardware Security Module (HSM). There are cloud solutions like CloudHSM from AWS that can help with that.